# Split string into multiple columns per character in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column where a string of characters represents a monthly series of events.

A str.split method would be ideal but I can't find the right pattern, regex or otherwise, to split on each character.

```
Col Foo
 BBBAAAAAR
```

into

```
Col Foo_1 | Col Foo_2 | Col Foo_3 | Col Foo_4 ...
B         |B          |B          |A          ...
```

I currently do it on a loop:

```
for keys, frames in data_frame_dict.items():
   temp1 = frames.Col_Foo.str.split(' ',expand=True).add_prefix('Feat_Mon_')
```

and then append...

Which works for spaces, but I want every character in a column, which right now has no separation between each element.

But I can't find the method pattern that works for a string of characters either here or in the docs.

EDIT: 
I have already tried '' as a separator and it returns the right amount of columns, but they're all empty. Its as if its splitting on each character and returning the empty space between characters.

Comment: `frames.Col Foo.str.split(' ',expand=True).add_prefix('Feat_Mon_') `  <----- use ` '' ` in place of  ` ' '`

Comment: I have already tried `''` and it returns the right amount of columns, but they're all empty. Its as if its splitting on each character and returning the empty space between characters.

Comment: but it works for us. can you show us the screenshot ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ugwWZw7

Comment: I see it works for a simple dataframe, thank you. I have converted the column to `string` just in case but its still not working. I'll investigate that, but this answers the initial question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to split by character, and the column is type `object`, you only need to do what you are doing but use the empty `''` instead of `' '` as an argument to `str.split`. This will split the word into all characters.

so the following code should work.

```py
frame['Col Foo'].str.split('',expand=True)
```

Comment: should be `frame['Col Foo'].str.split('',expand=True)`

Comment: mentioned in your comment above that I already tried this but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Are they all the same length?  I believe you could convert your Col Foo to a string and then just iterate through the string by character.  If they're all the same length, you could hardcode it to a df without a loop.
*Sorry, would've been a comment but I don't have the rep to comment

Comment: they can be variable length but there is a set maximum